# ¿Existe la manera de tomar la fecha del BIOS y guardarla en una variable?

Tags: java

No encuentro una forma de tomar la fecha del BIOS para hacer un Demo para una aplicacion de Java pero nada. Alguien tiene una idea? He probado con esto:

```
Date fecha12 = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

pero toma la fecha de windows que se puede cambiar y el demo se puede corromper si se cambia la fecha

Answer (score -1):

No conozco una  forma para acceder directamente a esa informacion desde java pero una alternativa es usar el comando **systeminfo** de la consola de windows(CMD) la cual ademas nos proporciona informacion adicional referente a nuestra maquina.

El unico incoveniente es que esta atado a la plataforma windows pero supongo que en otros sistemas existen alternativas similares.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
public class PCInformation {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("Bios Date is : "+getBiosDate());
        }

        public static String getBiosDate() throws IOException {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            String[] commands = { "systeminfo" };
            Process process = runtime.exec(commands);

            BufferedReader lineReader = 
                    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String biosInfo = lineReader.lines()
                                        .filter(line -> line.contains("BIOS"))
                                        .findFirst().get();


            String biosDate = biosInfo.substring(biosInfo.indexOf(",")+1).trim();
            return biosDate;
        }


}
```

*La funcion retorna un String, supongo que para ti no sera complicado hacer la conversion a Date o cualquier otro tipo de objeto para el manejo de fechas.